# Issue with Ableton Live Runnin' trought winehq

Tags: sound, wine, jack, daw

so, don't ask me why i don't use Bitwig, because i personally don't like it, i don't like lmms or ardour or reaper.
I'm an ableton user, my computer runs perfectly on UBUNTU 20.04 and i love this beautiful Os, but i only have a problem, i installed ableton live 10 on my linux via WineHQ and it runs perfectly, but i got A LOT of latency and that's drivin' me crazy.

I tried downloading a low latency kernel, and jackaudio with wineasio, i can only set it up with 512 of latency (Something like 16 ms) and it does good but when i'm looking for samples on my packs (Like drum kits and stuff) it sounds bad :( TOO BAD, of course that doesn't happen when i put them on my drum rack and i work with them but when i'm lookin for a new one SAME PROBLEM that happens in the browser of ableton.

My specs are
4 GB RAM
500 GB HDD
i7 3770 w/ Intel HD Graphics 4000

Any solutions? Thanks anyway :)

Comment: I'm in the same trench as you. If only ableton live runs well.... With wine and wineasio it's almost there. With buffers of 128 or 256, I don't get latency, but there are click and pops. And I have a decent machine a Lenovo Legion 5, 16 Gb of RAM and Ryzen 7. 4800H

Other programs go great. My plugins of AAS works awesome on wine. But Ableton Live...